# Is the pronunciation of "tu" "toosh?"

Tags: prononciation, voyelles

I thought "tu" was pronounced like English "to," but in this [link](http://www.memrise.com/course/691338/a1-french/1/garden/preview/), it's pronounced like "toosh." Does the audio sound like recorded by a native speaker of French? Which is correct and natural?

In case you can't log in to the website above, the example sentence was "comment t'appelles-tu ?" and I hear "sh" sound at the end clearly. Is there a dialect like that?

Comment: It is not like English "too." French has two different vowels in this region (seen in the words "tu" and "tout") and you need to be careful to distinguish them. French and English have different sound systems. The phenomenon that makes you hear a consonant sound at the end is explained here: http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/16320/words-ending-on-i-u-spoken-with-ipa-ɪç-is-there-a-system/16330#16330

Comment: Thanks! As for the vowel in "tu," it's the shorter version of the vowel in English "too": u vs. uː in IPA, right?

Comment: I was wrong; it's [y] vs. [uː ]. French one is more front, right?

Comment: It is more front in French, and also the type of rounding is a bit different. English /u:/ is often a bit fronter than French /u/, but it's usually not as front as French /y/.

Comment: https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/tu#Prononciation

Answer (score 1):

### English

You can hear a not too bad pronouciation of `tu` with google traduction.

Here an exemple : [link](https://translate.google.com/?hl=fr#fr/en/Tu%20vas%20au%20march%C3%A9.)

### Français

Tu peux écouter une prononciation pas trop mauvaise de `tu` avec google traduction.

Voici un exemple : [lien](https://translate.google.com/?hl=fr#fr/en/Tu%20vas%20au%20march%C3%A9.)