# Comment s'appellent ces modifications phonétiques en français ?

Tags: linguistique, phonétique

Il y a des gens qui, en français, ajoutent systématiquement un phonème additionnel à la fin des mots qui finissent en « **i** » ou en « **e** ». Je ne suis pas linguiste, mais il ressemble un peu au « ich » en allemand standard.

Pensez à « voici » ou « en effet ».

Il y a une autre modification phonétique qui a lieu parfois, qui consiste en *adoucir* certaines consonnes. Par exemple, « dire » se transforme en « djire », « partir » en « partchir » (désolé, je ne connais pas l'alphabet phonétique). J'ai observé ces deuxièmes modifications assez fréquemment en banlieue parisienne, mais pas seulement.

Ma question c'est : comment s'appellent ces modifications phonétiques ? Est-ce qu'il y a des textes de linguistique (sociale) qui les traitent ? Est-ce qu'elles sont traditionnelles de certains accents (par exemple, la première que j'ai décrite fait-elle partie de « l'accent parisien ?»)

Comment: Une question similaire en anglais: [Words ending on i/u, spoken with (IPA) ɪç – is there a system?](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/16320)

Comment: On pourrait aussi discuter de la (fâcheuse) habitude que des personnes "bobos" ont, de ralonger les sons /ã/ ou de rajouter des /hã/ aspirés au début ou la fin de mots. Le simple *allons au restaurant* qui se transforme donc en *allons au restauraaa[..]aaant-han*...

Comment: tlombart - celui-là semble être appelé "schwa prépausal" dans diverses études

Answer (score 8):

Le premier trait de prononciation est décrit comme "à la fin de certains groupes, la voyelle finale peut-être suivie d’un bruit de « friction »" dans [1], s'agissant d'un trait attribuable au français de la partie Nord de la France, spécifiquement Paris.

D'après [2], le deuxième trait se décrit comme "la palatalisation et l’affrication de /t/ et /d/ devant les voyelles /i/ et /e/". Il est associé à un parler populaire dit "de banlieue" (bien qu'il ne soit pas uniquement utilisé dans les banlieues). Cette forme de langage comporte d'autres modifications, v. ci-dessous.

D'après [3], qui cite [4], l'utilisation de ces traits de prononciation a été croisée avec des données socioéconomiques des locuteurs; ils étaient à l'époque plus fréquents chez les jeunes de 15-25 ans (ils ont grandi depuis, je ne sais pas si la tendance diminue toujours autant avec l'âge), de milieu modeste, et utilisé avec dans un contexte de proximité (famille, amis).

[1] *Phonologie du français contemporain* http://www.projet-pfc.net/pfc-presentation-du-francais-oral.html

[2] *Aspects phonétiques du "français parisien multiculturel": innovation, créativié, métissage(s)* https://halshs.archives-ouvertes.fr/halshs-00699516/document, p. 37-38:

> Parmi les principaux traits segmentaux que l’accent de banlieue partage avec le « français ordinaire », nous rappelons la simplification de groupes
>   consonantiques complexes (ex. autre [ot], lettre [lɛt], exprès [ɛspʁɛ]), l’élision de /l/ dans les pronoms il/ils et elle/elles (ex. ils me disent [imdiz], qu’est-ce qu’elle veut [kɛskɛmvø]) et l’assimilation consonantique (ex. je sais pas [ʃepɑ]). La palatalisation et l’affrication de /t/ et /d/ devant les voyelles /i/ et /e/ (ex. voiture [vwatʃyʁ], ce que tu dis [skətʃyʤi]) et dans une moindre mesure de /k/ et /g/ (ex. quartier [khaʁtʃʝe]), bien que connues de l’accent parisien populaire, semblent
>   aujourd’hui associées à l’accent des jeunes de banlieue, notamment d’origine maghrébine.

[3] *La variation sociale en français*, F. Gadet., Ophrys

[4] *Le français des banlieues: Uniformity and Discontinuity in the French of the Hexagone*, N. Armstrong / M. Jamin, in *French in and out of France*, K. Salhi (ed.)

Comment: Ajouté les titres.