# Mispronounciation - Tic de prononciation

Tags: prononciation

Certain people use to add a [ç]-like sound in the end of some words finishing by [i] or [e], like Cédric Villani at 3m48 (at the end of the word "entier") [in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xzVk56EKBUI).

Do you know the name of this habit ? Does it come from a specific region of France ?

Thanks !

Certaines personnes ont un tic qui consiste à ajouter une sorte de son [ç] à la fin de certains mots qui finissent par les sons [i] ou [e], écouter par exemple Cédric Villani à 3min48 (à la fin du mot "entier") [dans cette vidéo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xzVk56EKBUI).

Est-ce que vous savez si ce tic a un nom, s'il est typique d'un endroit en France ?

Merci !

Comment: Je ne dirais pas que ce soit « incorrect », c'est plutôt répandu. Cela dit, je ne sais pas s'il caractérise telle ou telle région, génération, etc. J'ai constaté que certains de mes profs canadien(ne)s l'employaient.

Comment: Cf. https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/16320/words-ending-on-i-u-spoken-with-ipa-%c9%aa%c3%a7-is-there-a-system, https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/19603/comment-sappellent-ces-modifications-phon%c3%a9tiques-en-fran%c3%a7ais, https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7460/are-there-different-pronunciations-for-merci

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Merci(h) ! réponse idéale de la part de Eau qui dort dans ce premier fil.

Answer (score 0):

This habit is not specific to a region of France. It is actually just that the person breathes out while pronuncing the final sound of the word, as he or she is thinking or hesitating.
Therefore it is not an accent.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree, but this leaves unresolved the question of why it's done in French, for example, and not English.

Comment: As a French I sometimes do it when I speak French, but probably  also when I speak English (I mean that I see no reason to have this habit only affect French words). For me the point is that it is not systematic, i.e. it can be used at a certain point in a conversation, but not for all occurrences of the words it concerns (or if it is, then I would say it's a mispronunciation). So it does not qualify as an accent, which would be systematic. But I don't know if in some regions of France it is used more than in others.

Comment: Francophones rather than Anglophones, then - same unexplained discrepancy.